# Loading a pair of floats into a vector type as though it were a double

Tags: c, optimization, sse, intrinsics, avx

I wish to broadcast load an `__m256` vector with the same 4 pairs of floats that are adjacent in memory.

That is, if I have some pointer to a float array `x` given by `{a, b}`, I wish to end up with an `__mm256` containing `{a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b}`.

My question is, are there any potential problems using [`_mm256_broadcast_sd`](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_avx_broadcast_sd.htm) to achieve this after casting `x` to be a double array?

So:

```
__m256 vect = (__m256)_mm256_broadcast_sd((double *)x);
```

Comment: `a` changed to `x` and cast inserted prior to assignment.

Comment: Much better. +1. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this safely; I have done this in the past. In my case, I was doing math using complex numbers where each component was held using a `float`. Using `mm256_broadcast_sd()` can be used to insert a single complex number into each of the 4 positions in the resulting `__m256d` instance, which you can then cast to a `__m256` if you want to do `float` operations on it.

Answer (score 2):

That will work just fine.

There is a small detail regarding 8-byte alignment *if alignment check is enabled*, however everyone runs with alignment check off, so this is not an issue in practice.